# Appeared purple shade after Nvidia driver installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I am trying to install Nvidia driver on my laptop with installed Ubuntu 16.04. The graphic card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M. I followed the instruction on the Nvidia website and downloaded the driver from here: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/136120/en-us. The installation process went well, the OS recognized the driver, but the colors in some programs have been changed: magenta shade is appeared. There is an example of same picture before and after installation the driver:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Why did it happen and how can I fix it?